# Check if a collection contain another collection?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-collection

Using Laravel Collection, what the good way to check if check if a collection (`$selectedItems`) contain another collection (`$orders`)?

I am currently using two foreach loop `$selectedItems` and check if it exist in the `$orders` using another loop.

```
   $selectedItems = collect([
        ["ItemId" => "T123", "Price" => "12.00"],
        ["ItemId" => "T99", "Price" => "13.00"],
    ]);

    $orders = collect([
        ["ItemId" => "T123", "Cost" => "12.00"],
        ["ItemId" => "T99", "Cost" => "13.00"],
        ["ItemId" => "T33", "Cost" => "13.00"],
    ]);

    $found = [];

    foreach ($selectedItems as $selectedItem)
    {
        foreach($orders as $orderItem)
        {
            if ($orderItem['ItemId'] !== $selectedItem['ItemId']) {
                continue;
            }

            $found[] = $orderItem;
        }
    }


    if (count($found) == $selectedItems->count()) {
        dd("Matched");
    } else {
        dd("Not Matched");
    }
```

How to also ensure the Price from `$selectedItems` is the same as Cost in the `$orders`

Comment: I solved the **contained** question. But I need more details about how exactly you expected to test the prices... are this supposed to happen after the contain test? Using the result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is the union collection function.

It merges the collections and gives you a unique subset of results. Meaning that duplicates are removed. This way you don't have to check if one exists in the other, just that you have a collection with unique values.

Read more about the union function [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/collections#method-union)

Edit: Because I misunderstood the intent of the original here is an answer that more correctly matches the intent.

```
$found = [];
$selectedItems->contains(function ($value, $key) use ($found){
    if($orders->contains($value)) {
        $found += [$key => $value]
    }
})
```

Comment: I don't want it to be merged.  I just need to know if all the item id from `$selectedItems ` contain in `$orders`.  If it is then just return true or false.

Answer (score 4):

```
$selectedItems->diff($orders)->isEmpty();
```

This will diff the second collection from the first and if the result is empty you can be sure that all your items exist in the other collection.

Answer (score 1):

```
$matched = $selectedItems->intersect($orders)->count() == $selectedItems->count();
```

Intersect returns a collection of selectedItems found in Orders.
When the count of this intersection == the count of the selectedItems then we know all selectedItems are in the interesected collection (and therefore all selectedItems are in Orders).

Answer (score 0):

```
$selectedItems = collect([
        ["ItemId" => "T123", "Price" => "12.00"],
        ["ItemId" => "T99", "Price" => "13.00"],
    ]);

    $orders = collect([
        ["ItemId" => "T123", "Cost" => "12.00"],
        ["ItemId" => "T99", "Cost" => "13.00"],
        ["ItemId" => "T33", "Cost" => "13.00"],
    ]);
// get orders and selected items ids as an array
    $ordersIds = array_map('array_shift', $orders->toArray());
    $selectedItemIds = array_map('array_shift', $selectedItems->toArray());
// check selected items ids exist in orders ids    
    $exist = count(array_intersect($selectedItemIds, $ordersIds)) == count($selectedItemIds);
// if exist, return true
    if ($exist)
        return true;
```

Comment: or false, it depends how you gonna use it

Comment: I just need to know if all the item id from $selectedItems contain in $orders. If it is then just return true or false.

Comment: `contains()` method of laravel, only checks by key, If you want to check whole collection, then you may use array methods

Answer (score 0):

I took a different approach than you to check if the $orders items keys are contained inside $selectedItems. But I think I got the expected result.

I created this function wrapping the code dealing with only this two arrays.

```
function checkContainsOrders($selectedItems, $orders)
{
    //Commenting this lines that are necessary only for Laravel Collection
    //$selectedItems = $selectedItems->toArray();
    //$orders = $orders->toArray();

    $selectedItemsKeys = array_column($selectedItems, 'ItemId');
    $orderItemsKeys = array_column($orders, 'ItemId');

    $intersectedValues = array_intersect($selectedItemsKeys, $orderItemsKeys);

    if (count($intersectedValues) === count($selectedItems) || count($intersectedValues) === count($orders)) {
        echo 'yup';
    } else {
        echo 'nope';
    }
}
```

You can see that I'm making use of `array_column` to extract only the column I want from both arrays and `array_intersect` for finding the matches between both.

My data is declared as arrays only:

```
$selectedItems = [
    ["ItemId" => "T123", "Price" => "12.00"],
    ["ItemId" => "T99", "Price" => "13.00"],
];

$orders = [
    ["ItemId" => "T123", "Cost" => "12.00"],
    ["ItemId" => "T99", "Cost" => "13.00"],
    ["ItemId" => "T33", "Cost" => "13.00"],
];
```

But you can easily convert a `collection` to an array using the method `toArray()` as I commented in the code.

Then finally executing and validating the result.

```
checkContainsOrders($selectedItems, $orders);
```

This code has been tested here: https://3v4l.org/JlCC8